# Swift - Use a variable from one ViewController in another

Tags: swift, variables, uiviewcontroller

I am currently building an application with Swift 3 and have defined a color in one `ViewController` with an `let ... = ...` statement and want to use this color in another `ViewController` too without defining it new. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to define that variable outside of class, for example

```
import UIkit

let color = UIColor.red

class ScanViewController: UIViewController  {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also you could override the init function of the another ViewController,
just like:

```
override init(withColor color: UIColor){
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil);
}
```

then you could pass the color as the param:

```
let viewController = ViewController(withColor: UIColor.red);
```

but I think the best way is define it globally.